# Accessing a module that belongs to a parent directory or to the module's sibling in python

Tags: python, python-module

I have already browsed all the topics close to this but couldn't find the answer to my question.

I have the following directory structure

`--Codes
+------mod_welch.py
+------__init__.py
+------Toy_Model
++---------__init__.py
++---------linear_filter.py`

Both of `__init__.py`'s are empty and I am trying to access to mod_welch.py in the body of linear_filter.py with no success. When I want to use realtive access to upper folders as 
`from ..mod_welch import welch` where welch is a function in`mod_welch` I receive:

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So far I found this hard-coding solution:
https://pythonadventures.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/import-a-file-from-another-directory-of-the-project/#comment-4483

Comment: Maybe the answers to this question may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python

Answer (score 1):

In genereal, your module should be `import`-ed somewhere and then used. Error message that you're receiving suggests that there is unusual execution method of module code. I suspect that youre testing your code by runnig `python linear_filter.py` (it gives the same error). Thats not the way.

As I said above you need to actually use your module if you want to test its functionality. To do that, you can `import` your module in another module or main script, for example:

```
from Codes.Toy_Model.linear_filter import some_method
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(some_method())
```

Where `some_method` is defined in `linear_filter.py` as:

```
from Codes.mod_welch import welch
def some_method()
    welch()
```

If that's not the case then please provide additional information about what is an usage (execution) method of your module -- which script are you running and how. Any `sys.path.append` magic etc. are important here too.